# Singleton design pattern example

Tags: java

I was studying the singleton pattern, and I saw the following example to understand this pattern:

```
public class SingleTonClass {
   //Static Class Reference
   private static SingleTonClass obj=null;
   private SingleTonClass(){
      /*Private Constructor will prevent 
       * the instantiation of this class directly*/
   }
   public static SingleTonClass objectCreationMethod(){
    /*This logic will ensure that no more than
     * one object can be created at a time */
    if(obj==null){
        obj= new SingleTonClass();
    }
        return obj;
   }
   public void display(){
    System.out.println("Singleton class Example");
   }
   public static void main(String args[]){
    //Object cannot be created directly due to private constructor 
        //This way it is forced to create object via our method where
        //we have logic for only one object creation
    SingleTonClass myobject= SingleTonClass.objectCreationMethod();
    myobject.display();
   }
}
```

I couldn't understood this line:

```
private static SingleTonClass obj=null;
```

or this line:

```
 public static SingleTonClass objectCreationMethod()
```

It is my first time to see the declaration of a method contains the name of the class.
I need an explanation for these two lines in detail.

Comment: The first line you quoted is a private static field named "obj". The type of the field is SingleTonClass. It is perfectly fine to have a class with fields that reference objects of the same class. The second line is a public static method which will return an instance of SingleTonClass when called. The name of the method is objectCreationMethod and it takes no parameters.

Comment: @DudeDoesThings Thank you  , but what is the meaning of a method that has the name of a class in its header  ? what does this means ?

Comment: As I explained in my previous comment, the part of the Signature (not header) you are referring to denotes the type of the returned reference. In this case the objectCreationMethod will return a reference of type SingleTonClass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line,

```
private static SingleTonClass obj=null;
```

declares a **static** variable of same class type `SingleTonClass`.

This above declaration is the standard method for implementing singleton classes as this static variable is the ONLY variable that will reference to just one object of Singleton class, that we will allow for creation and at the same time we declare the constructor as `private` so no other class can create the object of this class using `new` operator.

And this line,

```
public static SingleTonClass objectCreationMethod()
```

is another link to creation of Singleton class, where this method controls the creation and retrieval of the Singleton class's object.

Like I said above, constructor for Singleton class is made as private, so now we need some way to create or retrieve the Singleton class object and this method exactly does that. It is usually also declared as `getInstance()` is implemented as `public static`. Why public static, so that object of this Singleton class can be accessed by `Classname.getInstance()` and for your class it would be `SingleTonClass.objectCreationMethod()`

Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static SingleTonClass obj=null;
```

It is the SingleTonClass object and as you can see it is private so you cant modify the value, normally you would do

```
SingleTonClass obj = new SingleTonClass();
```

to create and object but in this case the constructor method must be private in this way you cannot create an object of this Class at all, the only way is through this method

```
public static SingleTonClass objectCreationMethod()
```

Are static because you cannot do `SingleTonClass obj = new SingleTonClass();`
You can access on this simple way

```
SingleTonClass myobject= SingleTonClass.objectCreationMethod();
```